# How I can read my file path and Schema from external files in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Scala and spark and wondering how to stop hard coding in scala using Intellij idea.

my schema is

```
val schema="actor_id int,first_name string,last_name string,last_update timestamp"

path = E:\Salman\Hive-Data\actor.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to hard code, you can make use of file to store configurations.

Then, you can use [Java properties class](https://www.javatpoint.com/properties-class-in-java) or [Typesafe Config library](https://lightbend.github.io/config/)   or [scala.io library](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-open-read-text-files-in-scala-cookbook-examples/) to retrieve those information in the code.

Let's say you want to read some files using spark API and you don't want to hard code file path.

First, create a file and save the information as shown below:

```
file1Path=/path/to/file1
file2Path=/path/to/file2
file3Path=/path/to/file3
```

code:

```
// Fetch configurations using Properties class
import java.util.Properties
import java.io._

val p=new Properties()
// pass configuration file name
p.load(new FileReader("configs.properties"))
val file1Path=p.getProperty("file1Path")
val file2Path=p.getProperty("file2Path")

// now use spark API
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val df1 = spark.read.csv(file1Path)
val df2 = spark.read.csv(file2Path)
```

No need to explicitly specify the schema while reading CSV. spark.read.csv will take care of that if we use the options as shown in following code,

```
val df = spark.read.option("inferSchema",true).option("header",true).csv(file1Path)
```

If you want to specify schema explicitly without hard coding then again, make use of previous configuration file.

Add following content to the file.

```
 file1Schema=actor_id int,first_name string,last_name string,last_update timestamp
```

code:

```
 //Fetch schema using previous property object
 val schemaString=p.getProperty("file1Schema")

// map for changing passed type to spark data type
val typeToSparkType = Map("int" -> IntegerType, "string" -> StringType,"date"->DateType,"timestamp"->TimestampType)

val colNameType = schemaString.split(",").map{s=>
    val values=s.split("\\s+")
    // Tuple of column name and type
    (values(0),values(1))
}

// prepare schema
var schema = StructType(colNameType.map(t => StructField(t._1, typeToSparkType(t._2), true)))

// read csv with custom schema
spark.read.schema(schema).csv(filePath1)
```

You can make of other alternative libraries which i mentioned in the beginning to read configuration files.